# How to show a similarity of two columns in percentage using R?

Tags: r, matrix, percentage, similarity

I have a simple question which I stock in it!
I have two data.frames and I want to compare them and show their similarity in percentage but I do not know how!

Here is a simple example:

```
   a <- as.matrix(rbinom(10,1,1/2))
    b <- as.matrix(rbinom(10,1,1/2))

    > a
              [,1]
         [1,]    1
         [2,]    0
         [3,]    1
         [4,]    0
         [5,]    1
         [6,]    0
         [7,]    1
         [8,]    1
         [9,]    1
        [10,]    0

   > b
         [,1]
     [1,]    1
     [2,]    0
     [3,]    1
     [4,]    1
     [5,]    0
     [6,]    0
     [7,]    0
     [8,]    0
     [9,]    1
    [10,]    0
```

I know that table shows the differences/similarities

```
   > table(a,b)
       b
    a   0 1
      0 3 1
      1 3 3
```

But how can I calculate the percentage for it? for example to show values in a are X% similar to b?

Comment: Perhaps `prop.table(table(a,b), 1)`  You can change the margin accordingly

Comment: @akrun I wouldn't marginalize. Just `prop.table(table(a,b))` may be clearer to know how many `a`s are equal to `b`s. Also `mean(a==b)` can give the percentage number of `a` elements equal to `b` elements.

Comment: @nicola My original comment was the same as yours.  Then, I thought the OP wanted with `margin`.

Comment: `table(a, b)/length(a)`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your comments, but what I meant was to show the over all similarity between two columns which in here if you look at these matrices they have 6 variables similar:

and the final similarity in percentage would be:
6/10 ==> 60%

I found the solution:

```
colSums(a==b)/length(a)*100
[1] 60
```

Comment: you can also do `percent(colMeans(a==b))`, `percent` being from `library(scales)`. Or `100*colMeans(a==b)` if you wanna have a number.