# Find column with values closest to vector

Tags: r, datetime

I have a vector containing times in milliseconds looking like this;

```
vector <- c(667753, 671396, 675356, 679286, 683413, 687890, 691742,
695651, 700100, 704552, 708832, 713117, 717082, 720872, 725002, 729490,
733824, 738233, 742239, 746092, 750003, 754236, 867342, 870889, 873704,
876617, 879626, 882595, 885690, 888602, 891789, 894717, 897547, 900797,
903615, 906646, 909624, 912613, 915645, 918566, 921792, 924625, 927538,
930721, 933542)
```

Now i want to look into a large data frame with a lot of time columns and search for  a single column that contains time values being closest (row-wise) to  my vector time values.

The data.frame containing all the columns is of the same number of rows. So lets say my vector has 240 elements, then every column in the larger data.frame consists of 240 rows.

Any idia how to do this ?

Comment: This is a fairly common question on stack overflow, please look first and share after you have hit a wall https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33038287/how-to-show-a-similarity-of-two-columns-in-percentage-using-r

Comment: I did. The difference is I dont know which columns to compare. Since there are 416, it makes it a bit different. Perhaps i should loop it?

Comment: I'll post an answer shortly but try `which.min(colSums(abs((v - Z))))
` where v is the vector and Z is the matrix. The result is the column number in Z with the smallest absolute difference from vector v.

Comment: @EvanFriedland Somehow this gives an error: Error in Math.data.frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the euclidean distance from your vector and each column of the dataframe and then check which column has the smallest distance:

```
which.min(sapply(1:ncol(dataFrame), function(i) sqrt(sum((t(v)-dataFrame[,i])^2))))
```

The above returns the index of the column with the lowest distance.

Where dataFrame is the data frame containing columns of different times(so we compare each column to the vector v) and v is the vector.

The following is just the square root of the sum of squared distances (euclidean distance):

```
sqrt(sum((t(v)-dataFrame[,i])^2)))
```

You can also use the following as a distance measure:

```
abs(t(v)-dataFrame[,i])
```

**EDIT**

As Evan Friedland pointed out you can actually just use:

```
which.min(colSums(abs(v-dataFrame)))
```

or

```
which.min(sqrt(colSums((t(v)-dataFrame)^2)))
```

Comment: Hey there Matt, you'' notice in my comment the same approach. You don't need to iterate over each column with sapply or even transpose the vector. R handles vector and matrix math when the sizes line up.

Comment: Yeah I edited it. My method was a bit redundant. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks Matt, this worked. I now can conclude that there are no columns which lay close enough to my vector to be accurate.

Comment: Bart, can I recommend you round up so you are not so granular as to use milliseconds? This might be more useful

Comment: @EvanFriedland, Yes i did